# How to create a float given an integer and the place of the decimal?

Tags: c, floating-point

How can you generate a floating point given an integer and the decimal position?

For example:

```
int decimal = 1000;
int decimal_position = 3;
float value = 1.000;
```

I have accomplished this by using powers but that is not efficient

```
decimal/pow(10, decimal_position)
```

Comment: like ... `decimal / 10^decimal_position` ? Now translate it into C.

Comment: How would you do it using pen and paper?

Comment: That's the most useful comment here, by @Someprogrammerdude. Think, before you do.

Comment: @achal That's not a bad method. Probably faster than using `pow()`.

Comment: And what do you mean by "that is not efficient"? Do you have any special requirements regarding "efficiency"? Have you measured and profiled to find out it's bottleneck in your program? You are sure it's not a case of premature optimization?

Comment: Please note `decimal * pow(10, -decimal_position)`... Which is sintactically nicer, just that.

Comment: Converting back and forth is most likely much  *less* efficient than using math.

Comment: If you have the GNU extension `exp10` available, that will be faster than `pow(10, decimal_position)`.  You can also reduce the division to a multiplication by negating `decimal_position` first.  I doubt any "clever" method will actually be faster than what you are already doing with those changes.

Comment: @iharobAlAsimi Why is multiplication better?

Comment: @AustenStone I did never say "*better*", just nicer, more beautiful and readable. Note that I come from a Physics school.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a few integer multiplications and one floating point division:

```
int decimal = 1000;
int decimal_position = 3;

int offset = 1, i;
for (i=0; i<decimal_position; i++) {
    offset *= 10;
}

float value = (float)decimal / offset;
```

Note that this works assuming `decimal_position` is non-negative and that 10<sup>decimal_position</sup> fits in an `int`.

Comment: This is not a correct answer.   `decimal_position` may well be large enough to overflow `offset`.  (Or even negative).  Iharob Al asimi's answer above is correct and best wrt numerical error.

Comment: Also, integer multiplies are generally less efficient that fp mulitplies, and both are likely less efficient than `pow`...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Why do you say integer multiplies are generally less efficient than floating-point multiplies? On common general-purpose processors, integer multiplies may have single-cycle latency while floating-point multiplies may have four-cycle latency. And how long do you think `pow` takes?

Comment: @EricPostpischil:  Generally fp mulitplies are pipelined and can issue every cycle (or multiple every cycle), while integer are not.  `pow` will at worst be the same as the mulitply loop and may be faster.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Floating-point multiplies are pipelined to compensate for their latency. They are harder than integer multiplies, requiring multiple stages and more gates. If they end up with the same throughput as integer multiplies or better, it is because more silicon has been given to them, not because they are more efficient. Integer multiplies are not pipelined typically because they are already single cycle. On macOS 10.13 on an Intel Core i7-3740QM, `pow(10, 3)` is about 100 cycles, while the code shown in this answer is about 8 cycles for 10^3 and 15 for 10^9.

Comment: @EricPostpischil:  The speed difference you're seeing is probably because the compiler you're using constant folds the loop but does not constant fold the pow for whatever reason.  FP mulitplies are ususally faster than integer multiplies of the same size, because the mantissa is narrower than the full width.  Of course an fp double (64 bit -- 51 bit mantissa) is likely slower than a 32-bit integer multiply, but faster than a 64 bit integer multiply.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: It is not. I checked the generated assembly. This is in a harness we regularly use for timing instruction sequences at a cycle level (and it includes techniques to remove various sampling noise). In this case, I marked the exponent and the result as volatile, so the compiler could not assume it knew the exponent value before execution of each loop, and it could not optimize away storing the result. The expected instructions were presented in the assembly language.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Having a narrower significand is insufficient to make floating-point multiplies faster than integer multiplies. The demands of handling NaNs, subnormals, infinities, rounding, shifting and exponent adjustment, inexact exceptions, overflow exceptions, and underflow exceptions cause floating-point multiplies to require more work than integer multiplies.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you generate a floating point given an integer and the decimal position?
>   I have accomplished this by using powers but that is not efficient

```
float value = decimal/pow(10, decimal_position);
```

---

It **depends on the range** of `decimal_position`.

With `0 <= decimal_position < 8`, code could use a  table look-up.

```
const float tens[8] = { 1.0f, 0.1f, ..., 1.0e-7f };
float value = decimal*tens[decimal_position];
```

Yet to handle all `int decimal` and `int decimal_position` that result in a finite value, using `float powf(float )`, rather than `double pow(double)`, should be the first choice.

```
//                    float power function
float value = decimal/powf(10.0f, decimal_position);
```

If not the best value is needed, code could `*`.  This is slightly less precise as `0.1f` is not exactly math 0.1.  Yet `*` is usually faster than `/`.

```
float value = decimal*powf(0.1f, decimal_position);
```

---

Looping to avoid `powf()` could be done for small  values of `decimal_position`

```
if (decimal_position < 0) {
  if (decimal_position > -N) {
    float ten = 1.0f;
    while (++decimal_position < 0) ten *= 10.0f;
    value = decimal*ten;
    while (++decimal_position < 0) value /= 10.0f;  // or value *= 0.1f;
  } else {
    value = decimal*powf(10.0f, -decimal_position);
  }
} else {
  if (decimal_position < N) {
    float ten = 1.0f;
    while (decimal_position-- > 0) ten *= 10.0f;
    value = decimal/ten;
  } else {
    value = decimal/powf(10.0f, decimal_position);  // alternate: *powf(0.1f, ...
  }
}
```

Select processors may benefit with using `pow()` vs. `powf()`, yet I find `powf()` more commonly faster.

---

Of course if `int decimal` and `int decimal_position` are such that an integer answer is possible:

```
// example, assume 32-bit `int`
if (decimal_position <= 0 && decimal_position >= -9) {
  const long long[10] = {1,10,100,1000,..., 1000000000};
  value = decimal*i_ten[-decimal_position];
} else {
  value = use above code ...
```

---

Or if `abs(decimal_position) <= 19` and FP math expensive, consider:

```
unsigned long long ipow10(unsigned expo) {
  unsigned long long ten = 10;
  unsigned long long y = 1;
  while (expo > 0) {
    if (expo % 2u) {
      y = ten * y;
    }
    expo /= 2u;
    x *= ten;
  }
  return y;
}

if (decimal_position <= 0) {
  value = 1.0f*decimal*ipow10(-decimal_position);
} else {
  value = 1.0f*decimal/ipow10(decimal_position);
}
```

Or if `abs(decimal_position) <= 27` ...

```
if (decimal_position <= 0) {
  value = scalbnf(decimal, -decimal_position) * ipow5(-decimal_position);
} else {
  value = scalbnf(decimal, -decimal_position) / ipow5(decimal_position);
}
```